# The Phone isn't switching on

Tags: settings, insider-preview

I use a Lava Iris Win1 Windows phone running on Insider Preview. I recently downloaded an update on the phone. It asked me to restart the phone and I did. 
But then, it isn't switching on :( it shows it's resting and after a minute, it shows ":(". How can I get it to start again? Is there a way out ?

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like you need to customer support.

Comment: How can i get it repaired ?

Comment: You could try to use the Windows Recovery Tool but be minded that it will delete everything on your phone and revert it to WP 8.1. [Here's the tool.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987)